# Check if matrix is Lower or Upper Triangular Matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

Is there an API in Eigen library to check if a matrix is a lower or upper triangular matrix?. Obviously, we can write a function to check this. But I would like to know if Eigen has a way of checking this. When I looked in the documentation, I read about triangular views, but no calls to check if it is lower or upper.

Comment: I don't know about built-in API's but something like comparing the eigenvalues to the diagonal will tell you.  There are more properties but that's the first one that came to mind.

Comment: This would just tell if the matrix is triangular or not. No? The eigen values for both of them will be the diagonal right? Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#title51

```
matrix.isUpperTriangular();
matrix.isLowerTriangular();
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how I missed looking at this. Works great.